# how to choose a python interpreter for Ansible playbook?

Tags: python, ansible

I have `python2.7` and `python3.5` in my `ansible` server , while executing playbooks it is using `python2.7`. I wanted `ansible` to use `python3.5` when executing playbooks.

```
 in order:
   1 have set export path.
   2 also changed default interpreter path in ansible.cfg as well.
   3 have given specific interpretor path in hostsfile for particular host.
```

But still, `ansible` is not running `python3`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to set the Python interpreter for individual hosts and groups, set the `ansible_python_interpreter` inventory variable.

If however, you want to set the Python interpreter for global use, then set the `interpreter_python` key in the `[defaults]` section in the configuration file `ansible.cfg`.

For a complete list of possible values for the two options above, please see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html

Also see this example for usage of `ansible_python_interpreter`: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/python_3_support.html , section "Testing Python 3 module support".

Answer (score 7):

1) There is [ANSIBLE_PYTHON_INTERPRETER](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python) configuration parameter to set:

> Path to the Python interpreter to be used for module execution on **remote targets**

2) The version of Python on **controller** depends on how Ansible has been built. For example

- [Ubuntu 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ansible) use Python 2.x

```sh
shell> grep DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"

shell> dpkg -l | grep ansible
ii  ansible                                2.9.6-1ppa~bionic

shell> ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /home/admin/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/admin/.ansible/my_modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) [GCC 7.4.0]
```

- [Ubuntu 20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ansible) use Python 3.x

```sh
shell> grep DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"

shell> dpkg -l | grep ansible
ii  ansible                               2.9.6+dfsg-1

shell> ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /home/admin/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/admin/.ansible/my_modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

- [Centos 7](https://cbs.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=27788) use Python 2.7 see [build.log](https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/ansible/2.9.2/2.el7/data/logs/noarch/build.log)
- [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=ansible&stype=all) use Python 3.x or Python 2.x

```sh
sheel> uname -a
FreeBSD master.example.com 12.1-RELEASE FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE r354233 GENERIC  amd64

shell> pkg info | grep ansible
py27-ansible-2.8.5             Radically simple IT automation
py36-ansible-2.8.5             Radically simple IT automation

shell> ansible --version
ansible 2.8.5
  config file = /home/admin/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/admin/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/local/share/py36-ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.9 (default, Nov 14 2019, 01:16:50) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 6.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_601/final 335540)
```